# symfony2.8 UserProvider‘s refreshUser() method seems superfluous

Tags: symfony, security, refresh

I used Symfony 2.8, I found UserProvider’s `refreshUser()` method like it has no purpose, since when I update the current user's role, the permissions won't immediately change unless I logout and login again. So I really do not understand the use of this method.

Such as when I add the current user's role ROLE_ADMIN, 
I dump($this->get('security.context')->getToken()) in my controller.
I found the token's roles does't change.
[dump info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wB9R.png)
[dump info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cajhk.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are using it correctly? Have you tried dumping your user before and after refresh? What are the results?

Comment: Yes I am sure.I have uploaded my dump results in my question.

Comment: Show the code, where you call it. And don't use screenshots, when the data is purely textual, please.

Comment: No matter which controller call, the results are the same.You can do your own experiment.

Comment: This attitude decreases your chances to get useful anwers.